# Solve a non linear system of first order ODES

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of ODEs but I am not quite sure how to go after getting it in the following form:

$$ \begin{cases} \dot x(t)= axy-xb+x^2 \\ \dot y(t)=-(a-1)xy \end{cases}$$
wihere $a,b>1$

Can anyone point at techniques to get closer to an explicit solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{cases} \dot x(t)= axy-xb+x^2 \\ \dot y(t)=-(a-1)xy \end{cases}$$
$$\dfrac {dx}{dy}=\dfrac { axy-xb+x^2 }{-(a-1)xy}$$
For $a\ne 1$ and $xy \ne 0$ ( read @Gonçalo's comment):
$$(1-a)\dfrac {dx}{dy}= a-\dfrac {b}{y}+\dfrac xy $$
$$y(1-a)x'- x= ay-b$$
This is a first order linear DE. You can try to solve it.

Comment: Yes you're right @Gonçalo